# TypeScript method to wrap any method of another class

Tags: typescript, strong-typing

I have the following setup in TypeScript:

```
abstract class Test {
    public abstract method1(param1: string): number;
    public abstract method2(param1: number, param2: string): Promise<number>;
}

class Wow {
    constructor(private test: Test) {}

    public fetch<K extends keyof Test>(key: K, params: Parameters<Test[K]>): ReturnType<Test[K]> {
        return this.test[key](params);
    }
}
```

But the `return` line inside the method `fetch` gives two errors:

> Type 'number | Promise' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Test[K]>'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Test[K]>'. (2322)

> Expected 2 arguments, but got 1. (2554)

I'm puzzled on why these errors appear and how to solve them.
What I want is for my method `fetch` to take a specific key of my `Test` class and be strongly typed with the proper parameters and return value of method specified by the `key`.

Comment: will you need `Test` as a class or is it okay to convert it into type/interface?

Comment: Needs to be a class because in my actual implementation it's not abstract and the methods call some webservices.

Comment: Do you just want to suppress the errors? Or convince the compiler that what you’re doing is safe?  The former is easy-ish, the latter requires some type juggling

Comment: @jcalz just out of curiosity, how would you do "type juggling"? I stuck [here](https://tsplay.dev/NlMXlm)

Comment: I’m on mobile now so I can’t work on it.  Will do when I get a chance

Comment: @jcalz I want to convince the compiler that what I'm doing is safe or, if it's not actually safe, find out what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Okay, does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAgP1w) meet your needs?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes, it does!

Comment: @jcalz [this other approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgKgU0gg3gLABQCCADgK4jICWsCokM8CAtthABYD2AJgEYAFOWAw2AgFwJmtAHYBzAJTS5lNiGxQA3CTJUa9RuGhxEHbvwBMIscAmr1mqABoKdtlemzFKhAAUoHjZaMGwAHjUNLQA+XVIKajoGHlTHaKgEAF4EADYSAF8SEggAT3JsBAB1GHIKqHDMGOyCBABtAGkEeQQAa2xSngAzLABdaUxO0YRsAA8IbDk+DCEhADoNsQUwaUo5XrkeAHc5NtGlbOa9g+O5C4B+BHXNqG3pfw9OLTBGqZiLrLNABKnEoUDkmHKEUmHVGzVU2AAbloEEViCQUGgMFVjgQ9EgeHJmJR4DwoCIoLREcAFggFpAJrgIBd8KjigkDMkEENOLAuOEunMFksMP1BiMasA6lpGkyYjEhGLpB03KJxDsAp8FlAfpLpQ0cJAYn8-CCIGCIVDwnr6rKjX88QkyFBQeCntxQmt6Yg0NVarbDRB-m0xaNnms1fYwEp4mQ0WigA)

Comment: @jcalz sorry for the double comment, but the link was too long and I couldn't write everything in one comment. Anyway, I built that other approach on top of yours, it also allows for dynamic types to be used. If you write an answer, could you please refer to that approach or both the initial one and that new one? Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, I realized there is a mistake in the other approach as I wrapped `Test` with `Wrapper` in the params and return type too, which shouldn't be. If you refer to that, please remove it.

Comment: I’m a bit confused; the question as asked isn’t about allowing dynamic types to be used, so I don’t know why I’d include that in an answer. Certainly you could go on to do such things in your own code, but it is somewhat out of scope for this question. Is it okay if I just answer the question as asked, with my solution as proposed?

Comment: @jcalz yes, it is, it would be awesome if you could put both approaches and list the second one as a plus, but it's fine if you don't

Comment: I played around with your code and couldn't quickly get it working without type assertions, and since I think it's mostly out of scope anyway, I'm not putting it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript can't really do much reasoning about [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  The [`Parameters<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utility types are implemented as conditional types, and thus `Parameters<Test[K]>` and `ReturnType<Test[K]>` are essentially opaque to the compiler.  The best it can do is to widen `K` to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints), `keyof Test`, and so you end up with a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of method names and a union of parameter lists.  And then the compiler gets confused because it can't be sure that `this.test[key]` actually accepts `params` as its parameter list, because maybe you're passing the `method1` params to `method2` or vice versa.  This is unlikely to actually happen (as long as `K` isn't specified with a union), but the compiler can't see that.  It has lost track of the *correlation* between `key` and `params`.   The general issue here is TypeScript's lack of direct support for what I call "correlated unions", as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)

The recommended fix for that issue is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The compiler is better about dealing with basic key-value interface types, and generic [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into such types and [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over them.

For your example, it means that we need to rewrite `Test` as such a mapped type.  Like this:

```
type TestParams = { [K in keyof Test]: Parameters<Test[K]> };
type TestReturn = { [K in keyof Test]: ReturnType<Test[K]> };
type TestMapped = { [K in keyof Test]:
  (...args: TestParams[K]) => TestReturn[K]
}
```

The `TestParams` and `TestReturn` types are the "basic key-value interface types", and `TestMapped` the mapped type over these types.  You can see that the type `TestMapped` is completely equivalent to the type `Test`, and indeed the compiler will allow you to assign a value of type `Test` to a variable of type `TestMapped`.

```
declare const t: Test;
const tM: TestMapped = t; // okay
```

And now you can rewrite `fetch()`:

```
class Wow {
  constructor(private test: Test) { }

  public fetch<K extends keyof Test>(
    key: K, params: TestParams[K]): TestReturn[K] {
    const thisTest: TestMapped = this.test;
    return thisTest[key](...params);
  }
}
```

Here the `params` input type and the return type are now written as generic indexes into our basic key-value interface types.  Inside the implementation, we assign `this.test` to a variable `thisTest` of type `TestMapped`, which enables the compiler to "see" what we're doing when we call `thisTest[key](...params)`.  The type of `thisTest[key]` is seen to be `(...args: TestParams[K]) => TestReturn[K]`, and the type of `params` is seen to be `TestParams[K]`, so calling the former with a spread argument list of the latter produces a result of type `TestReturn[K]`, which is the desired output type of the function.  So everything works.

Note that this refactoring caught an error: your code was of the form `thisTest[key](params)` instead of `thisTest[key](...params)`, meaning you passed the whole `params` array as the first argument instead of spreading it into multiple arguments.  If you left it that way you'd get the compiler error: `Argument of type '[TestParams[K]]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TestParams[K]'`, which hopefully would be enough information for you to fix the problem.

Now everything works as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.3#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgKgU0gg3gFAIIAOAriMgJawKiQzwIC22EAFgPYAmAjAApSwGCz4AuBI2oA7AOYBKSTPIsQ2KAG5iZSjToNocRG068ATEJHAxy1eqgAaMtZbnJ0+UoQAFKFxZqMGwAHhU1DQA+bQBfQkIIAE9SbCxcCB9XDABeAgQAbQBpBFkEAGtsRK4AMzTIAF1JTNF2DTAQnEgi+siEGO0klLqIACV2cigZBFz8AuLSiqrazohGhDGICZlMZNCV7t7+hN3hgFlgUhSeabyikqnFmuHGnQEAOg+ROTBJFeabMDdBTTXorDZbbqEOKEHjYFAiVKwLgyPAQX7pbRIlGICCndGQc6XbDXXIQTQIAD0FIQXDKwES8Xh6AQAHUuAB3Ag6LGMcjwLhQIRQagAN2AEFSEsg+IgwNm0JIFCotAQ1XYsA4IWK2AAHhKZDwMI9lulIgIdCRFpJCs5hKIfsN-ixAYV6t4weNJt0uSQSDycRwgisZYSrjdOEE3lKyRaEFBPVMI2B9ot6u8PnaAQptCRoTEgA)

Comment: Excellent explanation of the workings behind it all! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class Test {
  public abstract method1(param1: string): number;
  public abstract method2(param1: number, param2: string): Promise<number>;
  public abstract foo: () => number;
  public abstract bar: number;
}

class Wow {
  constructor(private test: Test) { }

  public fetch<K extends MethodKeys<Test>>(key: K, ...params: Parameters<Test[K]>): ReturnType<Test[K]> {
    return (this.test[key] as (...a: any[])=>any)(...params);
  }
  // if you want arglist param
  public fetchA<K extends MethodKeys<Test>>(key: K, params: Parameters<Test[K]>): ReturnType<Test[K]> {
    return (this.test[key] as (...a: any[])=>any)(...params);
  }
}

let x = new Wow(new Test())
x.fetch('method1', 'aa')
x.fetch('method2', 123, 'ss');
x.fetch('foo')

// note this doesn't method vs function prop
type MethodKeys<T> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends (...a: any[]) => any ? K : never]: 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but if I remove the type castings, I get the same errors. I would like to avoid type casting, otherwise I would have used them already.